# Alternative solution for looping through the Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, foreach, range

Recently I was wondering about the possibility of speeding up the program by switching a part of the code below:

```
Dim cell as Variant
Dim myValues() as Double
ReDim myValues(myRange.Count - 1)
Dim i as Integer: i = 0

For Each cell in myRange.Cells

    myValue(i) = cell.Value
    i = i + 1

Next cell
```

into a loop where I could refer to the value of each cell directly, instead of instantiating a cell object, assigning it a cell value from a given range, and then extracting the cell value.

In my mind, the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
Dim cellValue as Double
Dim myValues() as Double
ReDim myValues(myRange.Count - 1)
Dim i as Integer: i = 0

For each cellValue in myRange.Cells.Values
    myValues(i) = cellValue
    i = i + 1
Next cellValue
```

If my overall concept is wrong from the start, or if you can't get the cells values from Range faster, then there was no question.
Due to the fact that this is my first post, I could have written something incorrectly / in wrong posting convention. Let me know and I'll fix it.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking. You can assign a range to an array without a loop, e.g. `myValues=range("A1:A10").value`. Plenty on this online.

Answer (score 0):

As @SJR notes, this is a common way to access data from a range without going cell-by-cell

```vb
Dim arr, i as long, rng As Range

Set rng = Activesheet.Range("A1:B20")

arr = rng.Value  'arr is now a 2D array (1 To 20, 1 To 2)
                 'Note: base is 1 and not the more-typical 0

For i = 1 to ubound(arr,1)
     Debug.Print arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)
Next i

arr(3, 2) = 999

rng.value = arr 'put the data back to the range
```

Answer (score 0):

If the reason is for getting rid of the 2D array a function like this can be the solution:

```
Function VectorFromRange(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arrIn As Variant
    arr = rng.value 'Dumping the data from range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim item As Variant
    ReDim arrOut(1 To rng.Cells.Count) As Variant
    For Each item In arr
        i = i + 1
        arrOut(i) = item
    Next item
    VectorFromRange = arrOut
End Function
```